# Is Base64 good for encoding strings for a search engine database?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, base64, search-engine

I've a strange problem. I made a web where I can write post with title, the whole information is stored on a database after being encoded with base64.

I tried to make a engine search to look for the post using the title, but it doesn't work correctly. The titles are just one word long so if I only write a letter from the word it should return the full name, but it doesn't return it.

Can anybody help me with this? Should I change the encoding method?
I need to encode the information but I have to recover it after, that's because I decided to use Base64.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Why are you using base64 encoding in the 1st place??

Comment: To encode strings with base64 for storing in a database is a bad idea. I recommend to store strings as plain strings in VARCHAR columns with an appropriate collation.

Comment: 1º I'm using base64 because I thought it was a good idea. 2º Isn't dangerous to store data without encoding? I'm a bit confused about this.

Comment: It's not dangerous at all to store strings as plain strings in VARCHAR columns. It's what databases are made for (not only).

Comment: Um... Alright I'll use plain strings though only for the title, I feel better knowing all the data is encoded though on a bad way(Base64). ;)

Comment: Base64 is JUST a form of encoding, its not an encryption - it offers absolutely zero security  over plain text. It can be decoded by anyone. There is no point doing this.